# Фильтр записей по дате и количечтву просмотров WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как реализовать вывод записей определенной рубрики, с фильтром записей по дате и  количечтву просмотров WordPress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как вы храните количество просмотров?

Comment: В произвольных полях к записям или/и страницам. В интернетах много плагинов и готовых php функций, которые будут считать просмотры и записывать их в поле в каждом посте.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте 'orderby' в аргументах

Answer (score 1):

А $args указываем слаг типа таксономии, и значение ему ставим ярлык нужного элемента таксономии. Например:

```
$args = array ( 'my_category' => 'slug_of_need_cat', ...some other params...);
```

А для фильтрации по дате и количеству просмотров - обратите внимание на параметр meta_query в том-же args.

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](http://dontforget.pro/wordpress/filtr-postov-po-proizvolnyim-polyam-v-wordpress/) очень хороший пример. Сам в начале ничего не понимал, но за 1-2 дня самостоятельно разобрался и на этом примере сделал сортировку с расширенным функционалом ([пикча](https://s3.amazonaws.com/media-p.slid.es/uploads/368247/images/1677771/45.jpg)). Я бы код скинул, да осталась только php функция.